# How to deal with feature and target variable at different granularities?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, modeling, feature-engineering

I am dealing with a dataset in which the feature data have different granularity of the target variable. Specifically, while the features I use to train the model are minute-based (so that I have an observation every minute), the target variable is weekly-based (so that I have an observation every week).

What I tried is the following:
1. Aggregating somehow (by using median, mean or other statistics) feature data to have the same granularity of the target variable (with the side effect of losing really a lot of information)
2. Interpolating the target variable in time to have the same granularity of feature data (with the side effect of introducing really a lot of noise).

Are there any other approaches or statistical/machine learning models to deal with this kind of problem? What should be the best approach to use why? I am not an expert, but maybe a HMM could help?